nginx can't load php v8.2
Can you look what is wrong in my nginx config file ?
user root root;
worker_processes auto;
worker_cpu_affinity auto;
master_process on;
worker_priority 10;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
events {
worker_connections 512;
}
http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
default_type application/octet-stream;
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status '
'"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
sendfile on;
client_max_body_size 100M;
server {
listen 85;
server_name FreshTomato;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
location / {
root /opt/www;
index index.html index.htm index.php ;
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location /50x.html {
root /opt/www;
}
location ~ ^(?<script_name>.+?\.php)(?<path_info>/.*)?$ {
try_files $script_name = 404;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/var/run/php8-fpm.sock;
}
location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/ {
root /opt/www;
expires 10d;
}
}
error_page 405 =200 $uri;
}
}


Nginx can't load php files after I change fastcgi_pass parameter(404 not found error).
Nginx v1.27.0
PHP v8.2 after changing from v8.3.9 (because I need working imagick module).
PHP v8.3.9 is installed in my router firmware but unfortunately can't load imagick module.
I read before tutorials and other forum posts but for me this config file looks ok. Really I don't know what can be wrong.
This is my first time when I try to run my web server(through LAN network only) with php & mysql.
